# Is it possible to pass an array from onClick to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, input

In PHP I can write a function like this:

```
function myFunction(myArray)
{
    foreach(myArray)
    {
        // do stuff with array
    }
}
```

Then I can call it like this (maybe ugly, but still works):

```
myFunction(array("string1","string2"));
```

I want to do something similar with JavaScript but can't figure out if it's possible to pass arrays to functions like that. This is my psuedo-function:

```
function myFunction(myArray)
{
    for (index = 0; index < myArray.length; ++index)
    {
        // do stuff with array
    }
}
```

I want to call it from a button using onClick like this:

```
<input type="button" value="myButton" onClick="return myFunction(array("string1","string2"))">
```

Can this be accomplished in a simle way?

Comment: Just use the array literal, ["value1","value2"]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's *possible*. You'd probably want to use array initializer syntax (aka an "array literal"), and you need to mind your quotes:

```html
<input type="button" value="myButton" onClick="return myFunction(['string1','string2'])">
```

If your attribute value is quoted with double quotes, you can't use a literal double quote *within* the value. The easiest thing is to use single quotes, although since the text of attribute values is HTML text (something people tend to forget), you *could* use `&quot;` if you liked. (I wouldn't. :-) ) And the fact that the text is HTML is something to keep in mind for the contents of the array...

It may well not be *desirable*, though. You might consider using modern event handling techniques to hook up the handler, for instance:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=button][value=myButton]").addEventListener("click", function() {
    myFunction(['string1','string2'])
}, false);
```

Or if you have multiple of them:

```js
const handler = () => {
    myFunction(["string1","string2"]);
};
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button][value=myButton]")) {
    element.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
}
```

In that latter case, if all the elements are in some container (and ultimately they are, even if the container is just `document.body`), you might be able to use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) to hook up a single handler and then see if the event passed through the relevant element:

```js
theContainer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const button = event.target.closest("input[type=button][value=myButton]");
    if (button && this.contains(button)) {
        myFunction(["string1","string2"]);
    }
});
```

Comment: I know it's not desirable but right now it just want something simple and basic... Thanks!

Comment: @TorbjörnLokeNornwen: I said *"**may** not be"*. :-) Glad that helped!

Comment: what if the array is a very long one represented by a variable?

Comment: @user7344209 - The size doesn't matter in that case, but the variable would need to be a global to be used in an `onClick` atttribute event handler (so you'd want to use the `addEventListener` version instead).

Comment: answer is a little dated - I'm just wondering if this is still the most effective way to do it. It does still work at the end of 2022, but I'm always looking for efficiencies.

Comment: @jpgerb - Not a lot has changed about this since 2015 if working directly at the DOM level. But I removed some outdated stuff about old versions of IE, and added event delegation as an option.

Comment: @RaymondChen What about stringify? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp  Then it's just a long string that you can parse later?

Comment: @jpgerb - I don't see what stringify has to do with this...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I'm thinking that if you had the array, you could stringify it into a string, then it's easier to pass between functions. Instead of `myFunction(array("string1","string2"));` it would be `myFunction(stringsRfun);`

Comment: @jpgerb - My impression is the OP's starting point is two hardcoded strings. I'd avoid using the attribute thing entirely, though, frankly. I only describe it above because the OP asked if it was possible. I'd use one of the modern alternatives instead.

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 problems. `array` should be `Array`, as JS is case-sensitive. You could also use the short form `[1,2,3]`. Then notice that your `onclick` attribute is wrapped with double quotes. You need to escape the quotes inside your JS by doing `\"` or by simply using `'`:

```js
function myFunction(arr){
  // for demo purposes
  alert( JSON.stringify(arr) );
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="myButton" onClick="return myFunction(['string1','string2'])">
```

I would also suggest **avoiding inline JS** as [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963562/is-it-possible-to-pass-an-array-from-onclick-to-javascript-function/28963651#answer-28963589) mentioned it.